# Trying to use custom code to Adobe PDF Text Box for Calculation

Tags: javascript, adobe

So I am trying to add the below custom code to a text box in adobe pdf as a calculation. I dont not receive an error but the field in question doesnt return the value i expect (it shows nothing at all). This tells me that my syntax is probably good, and Im just referencing the other objects incorrectly.

Anyone want to enlighten me?

```
const weightedAverage = (nums, weights) => {
  const [sum, weightSum] = weights.reduce(
    (acc, w, i) => {
      acc[0] = acc[0] + nums[i] * w;
      acc[1] = acc[1] + w;
      return acc;
    },
    [0, 0]
  );
  return sum / weightSum;
};



weightedAverage
    (
        [
            this.getField('Manager Review2022 Leadership Behaviors Level I').value
            , this.getField('Manager Review2022 RC Ops Manager Outcomes').value
            , this.getField('Manager Review2022 Core Principles').value
        ]
        , 
        [
            0.3
            , 0.4
            , 0.3
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out you have to assign the value TO something, example:

```
 event.value = 'your variable here'
```

I ended up taking a different approach, which i admit is AWFUL but it helped learn what I was doing wrong. There obviously is room to clean this up and do it in a more elegant way, but since no one seemed to chime in with detaisl I think it might help others who come after me.

```
    // Acquire Inputs
    var nBehaviors = Number(this.getField("Manager Review2022 Leadership Behaviors Level I").valueAsString);
    var nOutcomes = Number(this.getField("Manager Review2022 RC Ops Manager Outcomes").valueAsString);
    var nPrinciples = Number(this.getField("Manager Review2022 Core Principles").valueAsString);



    // Perform Calculation
    var nBevCalc = nBehaviors * 0.3
    var nOutCalc = nBehaviors * 0.4
    var nPrinCalc = nBehaviors * 0.3
    var nSumofThings = nBevCalc + nOutCalc + nPrinCalc
    var nWeightedAvg= nSumofThings / 1;
      
    // Assign Result to Field
    event.value = nWeightedAvg;
```